# Can you set a property in a linq query before selecting the item?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, linq-to-objects

Is there any way to set a property in the middle of a query?

```
var products = from p in Products
               let pricecalc = p.IsDiscontinued ? 0 : p.UnitPrice
               // somehow set p.Price = pricecalc
               select p;
```

I know i could use  `select new Product { .. set props here .. }` but i dont want to do this.

At the moment, i am thinking i am going to have to use a `foreach` to do this.

Comment: You _could_ hack this into LINQ, but you'd be better off making it clear what you're doing and why in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 let pricecalc = p.IsDiscontinued ? 0 : p.UnitPrice
```

Use

```
 let pricecalc = (p.Price = p.IsDiscontinued ? 0 : p.UnitPrice)
```

Comment: This worked in my code (Entity Framework), (but not in LinqPad, linq to sql). It's the most clean (even though i hate it) :). So you get the the tick :)

Comment: i tried first in linqpad (and trust me it is working), and then only pasted here. For linq to sql, i am not sure as linq query gets translated to SQL query

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need an extension method:

```
public static TSource Apply<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> action)
    where TSource : class // wouldn't work for value types, since the action would work on a copy
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var products = Products.Apply(p => p.Price = p.IsDiscontinued ? 0 : p.UnitPrice);
```

However I wouldn't recommend doing this; Linq queries are not supposed to produce side effects. You should probably change your query to return new objects that contain the updated price.

Answer (score 1):

```
Products.Select(p => {
    var pricecalc = p.IsDiscontinued ? 0 : p.UnitPrice;
    p.Price = pricecalc;
    return p;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* work this into a LINQ statement, but as far as I know there's no way to do it explicitly without some kind of workaround.

Something like this will take care of it without the need for any extra methods:

```
var products = from p in Products                
    let pricecalc = p.IsDiscontinued ? 0 : p.UnitPrice                
    //introduce a throwaway let variable, just to modify something on p
    let ignored = p.Price = pricecalc
    select p;
```

As others have said, I would recommend against this approach.